# Missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory in @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot

Hi i have written a test, which looks like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,classes={MyApplication.class})
@DataJpaTest
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
    ....

    @Test
    public void myTest(){
    ....
    }
}
```

The Application looks like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
@ComponentScan("de.myfirm.myservice.service")
public class  MyApplication{
....
}
```

In the pom.xml i have the folllowing dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The Application is a Web Service which uses Jersey. When the application is started the embedded servlet container is started as expected. In the test i get the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
....
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
....
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

Answer (score 2):

i found out that @SpringBootTest and @DataJpaTest does not work together , see this issue

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6345

Comment: Yup, you will get the same problem with `@RestClientTest` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You are excluding `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` in pom.xml.
To run spring boot test with embedded tomcat you will need this dependency.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```